# Apache for Ångström Linux

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I need to install Apache webserver for Ångström (Angstrom) Linux. Is there a separate distro I need? Where would I get that? Can I install normal apache distro into Ångström Linux? Any help in this regard is welcome.

Comment: armstrong? Ångström?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Angstrom Package browser](http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/repo/?pkgname=apache2),  There is a version of apache2 for this distribution.

So I assume you can use the Angstrom distro's package manager, which from my limited googling appears to be `opkg`.

At a wild guess, try `opkg install apache2`, and see what happens?

Comment: A better answer than the question deserved.

Comment: The link to the angstrom package browser is dead.